Why do survey compasses have a cotangent table?
I have noticed that survey compasses often have a cotangent table printed somewhere on them. What is the intended use for this table? (I am not a surveyor or geologist and have never used these beasts; my only compass experience is with baseplate compasses for orienteering and land navigation.)
(Just to be clear, I’m not asking what the cotangent is in general terms; I am asking why it, among all trig functions, got picked to feature in the limited space at the back of a compass.)
Addendum
It occurred to me overnight that I might be looking at the wrong instrument. These gadgets often seem to double as clinometers, set up so that they show the angle from the vertical. This means, that to find the height of an object, one could measure the distance to the object, then sight the top with the clinometer, and multiply the distance with the cotangent of the clinometer reading. Is this why the table was put there?
